# How can I put a conditional validation on an ActiveModel attribute that has several validations already?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic which by default puts a few validations(length, uniqueness, format, etc) on fields like login, email, and password.

I'd like to be able to skip all validations attached to one of the attributes if, say, another attribute is present.

Is this possible?  Something like:

```
validate :email, :unless => :has_openid?
```

which will then skip the format, length, and uniqueness validations just on the email attribute.

I'm working with a Rails 3.1.x app and authlogic 3.1.0

Update: I was trying to follow this article, but I couldn't get it to work properly:
http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=242

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this with authlogic is by passing a block to `acts_as_authentic`:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  with_options :unless => :has_openid? do      
    config.merge_validates_format_of_email_field_options
    config.merge_validates_length_of_email_field_options
    config.merge_validates_uniqueness_of_email_field_options
  end
end
```

Comment: true, i can do this, but it couples it to the specific set of validations on that attribute.  For example, what if I add a gem or add any other validation to the email field...I'd then need to remember to update this block as well...see what I mean?

Comment: That's fair. When you say it "doesn't work", what behavior are you seeing? Is it trying to validate the field no matter what?

Comment: when I followed the article the save was failing but there were no error messages which I found to be super weird...I didn't dig too deep into it and i've since abandoned that approach so I can't tell you exactly what was going on.  I was looking into writing my own module which loops through all User.validators and adds and if/unless option...but I found that the rails source freezes the options hash upon initialization [lib/active_model/validator.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2e62af310d98fba78f338d916f7c17996446bc40/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb)

Comment: hm, ok. You could try `dup`ing the hash if you want to modify it.

Comment: sure, the beauty of ruby is that you can do anything you want, like dup'ing the hash and then doing and instance_variable_set...but "should" i do that is the question...i could also monkey patch ActiveModel::Validator as well...I was hoping there was a better way...

Comment: If you're that experienced in the language, why not just debug the problem you're having? I use the exact technique from your original post in my own app and it works fine. It sounds like you you're good enough to figure out what's going on. If I knew you were as good as you're coming off I would have suggested that in the first place.

Comment: I have been debugging the problem, but have unable to come up with a solution.  Hence, me reaching out to the community :)  It was taking too long for "proper" solution, so I wrote a workaround and put it in a gem, whose solution and url I will list below

Answer (score 0):

I've written a workaround and abstracted it out into a gem: 
https://github.com/synth/conditional_attribute_validator

Gemfile:

```
gem 'conditional_attribute_validator', :git => "git://github.com/synth/conditional_attribute_validator.git"
```

Example:

```
class User
  include ConditionalAttributeValidator

  validate_attributes_with_condition :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :unless => :has_another_form_of_authentication?
end
```

Source:

```
def validate_attributes_with_condition(*args)
  opts = args.extract_options!
  raise "Must have an :if or :unless option" unless opts.has_key?(:if) or opts.has_key?(:unless)

  merge_methods = self.methods.grep(/merge_.*_options/)
  args.each do |field|
    merge_methods.grep(/#{Regexp.quote(field)}/).each do |m|
      self.send(m, opts)
    end
  end
end
```

Rails automagically creates the merge_*attr*_options methods based upon whatever validations have been specified in order to merge options into an existing validation.  So I lookup these methods and iterate over them and check if that method applies to a particular field.  If so, I call the merge_*attr*_options method and pass in the options.

I'm not too concerned about performance since this is just performed on initialization.